# 3-phase autotransformer bank

Tags: transformer

The question is:

[image]

The solution is:

[image]

What does the winding apparent power represent?

I mean two windings each is 16.5 MVA gives a sum of 33 MVA.

This is not the same value as the 60 MVA. Why?

Source:

NCEES

PE Electrical and Computer: Power Practice Exam, 2020

ISBN 978-1-947801-16-5

Comment: The answer is (D) so, why does the solution you have offered go round the trees to get there?

Comment: @Andy aka I know the answer, you know I am just confused why the total winding apparent power which is 33 MVA is not equal to the input or out put apparent power!

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding, you should consider a transformer with primary W1 rated (79.7-57.7)kV x 753 A, and secondary W2 rated 57.7 kV x  286.2 A.
Aparement power is 16.5 MVA, windings and  magnetic core is rated for this parameters.  "I mean two windings each is 16.5 MVA gives a sum of 33 MVA" is not correct.
The device input aparent power is 79.7 kV x 753.1 A = 60 MVA; the output current is the sum of the primary winding current I1 + secondary winding current I2 , so the device output power is 57.7 kV x 1039 A.
The advantage of an autotransformer configuration is that input current (or primary winding current) is added to secondary winding current, and because of this you have different aparent power for windings and for the device.